# OpenStack connect two subnets from different projects

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

in my OpenStack setup I have one tenant with different projects and I'm trying to figure out what would be the best approach to make communication between the
subnets 10.200.0.0/24 <-> 10.202.1.0/24 of two projects
possible (see picture below).

Would that be by creating a shared network and connect GW01 and GW02 to it with static routes?
or is there a thing such as "shared router"?

I am a bit lost in the endless possibilities of OpenStack and would appreciate any help/hints.

[image: osc-network-layout]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a tenant with different projects. Tenants and projects are used interchangeably in OpenStack ;) There is an effort to change the name to project everywhere, but references to tenants can still be found in many places.

Comment: OP doesn't use the term "tenant" in the original OpenStack sense. What's meant is probably a customer in a public cloud, which would be modeled by a Keystone domain.

Comment: by 'tenant' I meant 'domain'. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not dare to claim that I have the 'best' approach for you. I can tell what my initial idea would be.

You can share networkB with ProjectA using the instructions here: https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/admin/config-rbac.html. Now if you create a router in ProjectA, you can add interfaces for it in the subnets in networkA as well ass the subnets in networkB. Because the router knows both networks, you don't need to add static routes to route between them.

Comment: Hi @BakaKuna. Your suggestion to share a network worked instantly. Thanks. Haven't seen that option before. 
However, even though I added the interface to my router, I am not able to access the instances on networkB from networkA. I already made sure the security-groups are set correctly. The question is: is the router not routing or can I simply not access instances within projectB?

Comment: all right, i figured it out. when attaching networkB to GW01 i need to make sure that the gateway-ip from networkB remains the same (obvious, but I still did it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct solution:

1. Create a port on shared network
2. Attached the port by openstack CLI to each tenant ( project ) router

[image]